# Visual Studio 2008 does not add control to designer file when adding it into a Telerik RadGrid EditFormTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid to display data gathered from various xml files.
I have defined an EditFormTemplate where additional data can be seen/edited.
Now whenever I add controls into this template, the designer doesn't add the necessary control to the designer.cs codebehind file. Why?

Edit:
Most specifically, I have a asp:DropDownList that I want to initialize with a preselected value. I've tried doing this in the PageLoad of the CodeBehind, and even in a separate EventHandler that I bound to onInit and onLoad of the control. Both of these get called, but the control "doesn't seem to exist" for the codebehind.

I used FindControl, and cast the result to a DropDownList object, but this seems to return null.

Comment: Does the designer add the control to the designer? If so, then add one, do a save, close all files, then open the page again in the designer. See if the added control is present.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't access the control from the codebehind?  If so you need to do this using FindControl.

Comment: @John Saunders, yes the control gets added to the design view. But it does not get added to the partial class file created by the designer. Closing and reopening does not fix this. The code in the aspx gets generated too, by the way.

@Sean Molam, exactly. This sounded very good, but this produces another *System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* which i've come to hate that much since I've started programming with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preselecting a value for a DropDownList is done like this:
`<asp:DropDownList SelectedValue='<%# Bind("codeBehindVariable") %>' runat="server" ID="id" />`
I just wonder why I missed this property of asp:dropdownlist when i was looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web site (created with File->New Web Site) or a Web Application Project (created with File->New Project)? In a web site, there is nothing added to the partial class file. It's all built by magic at runtime.

Does the grid not display when you open the page in a browser?

Comment: It is a project, and the RadGrid does get added to the partial class file. I can access the RadGrid in the CodeBehind.
Also, the grid shows up, and displays the data.

Comment: I'm awake now. You're talking about controls in a template. The template is only instantiated at runtime. It's not meant that the controls should ever exist in any source file. Try this with a simple Repeater control, and you'll see the same thing.

Comment: Good morning :) So this solves my question, but of course means I still can't have a preselected value for the DropDownList. There must be another way though, right?